# Nameless array in Typescript class?

Tags: arrays, typescript, class

I'm relatively new to Typescript.

I am working through a tutorial and have some code like this:

```
export class Brushes {
  [key: number]: Brush;
}
```

As far as I can tell, it creates an indexable class so that I can do things like

```
const brushes: Brushes = {...}
```

and then

```
mybrush = brushes[2];
```

or whatever.

My question is, how do I tell what the total length of this "array class" is, since

```
mybrush.length;
```

is undefined?

Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: You've not actually created an array here, you've just created a regular JS object. JS allows you to index objects with both strings and numbers, and doesn't automatically keep track of how many fields you've assigned to your object.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach. Instead of creating an "indexable" class, I'd just store instances of the class in an array.

```
const brush: Brush = {...};
const arrayOfClasses = [];
arrayOfClasses.push(brush);

const myBrush = arrayOfClasses[0];

arrayOfClasses.length; ## 1
```

Would that be applicable given your use case? Or do you need to use classes for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- I'm not sure why the tutorial decided to make it a class like that.  It seems like a strange construct to me.  What I really want is an indexable property of a class, I think.